# Visualizing decision tree in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, decision-tree

I am trying to design a simple Decision Tree using scikit-learn in Python (I am using Anaconda's Ipython Notebook with Python 2.7.3 on Windows OS) and visualize it as follows:

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
from sklearn import tree
from os import system

data = read_csv('D:/training.csv')
Y = data.Y
X = data.ix[:,"X0":"X33"]

dtree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy")
dtree = dtree.fit(X, Y)

dotfile = open("D:/dtree2.dot", 'w')
dotfile = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file = dotfile, feature_names = X.columns)
dotfile.close()
system("dot -Tpng D:.dot -o D:/dtree2.png")
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I use the following blog post as reference: [Blogpost link](http://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/learning-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn-package/)

The following stackoverflow question doesn't seem to work for me as well: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570042/visualizing-a-decision-tree-example-from-scikit-learn)

Could someone help me with how to visualize the decision tree in scikit-learn?

Comment: Does the file `dtree2.dot` get created?

Comment: Can you debug the `export_graphviz` line as this is returning `None` so some error has occurred

Comment: Yes. dtree2.dot does get created.

Comment: Scikit-learn from version `0.21` has method [`plot_tree`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html) which is much easier to use than exporting to graphviz. Anyway, there is also very nice package [`dtreeviz`](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/tree/master/dtreeviz). Here is a comparison of the visualization methods for sklearn trees: [blog post link](https://mljar.com/blog/visualize-decision-tree/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`sklearn.tree.export_graphviz`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) doesn't return anything, and so by default returns `None`.

By doing `dotfile = tree.export_graphviz(...)` you overwrite your open file object, which had been previously assigned to `dotfile`, so you get an error when you try to close the file (as it's now `None`).

To fix it change your code to

```
...
dotfile = open("D:/dtree2.dot", 'w')
tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file = dotfile, feature_names = X.columns)
dotfile.close()
...
```

Comment: This does get rid of the error but the following command doesn't produce the plot: 
system("dot -Tpng D:/dtree2.dot -o D:/dtree2.png"). However, dtree2.dot file gets created.

Comment: I don't know anything about using graphviz sorry. It's best if you ask a new question as that's a different problem entirely.

Answer (score 39):

Here is one liner for those who are using **jupyter** and sklearn(18.2+)  You don't even need `matplotlib` for that. Only requirement is [graphviz](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz)

```
pip install graphviz
```

than run (according to code in question X is a pandas DataFrame)

```
from graphviz import Source
from sklearn import tree
Source( tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns))
```

This will display it in SVG format. Code above produces Graphviz's [Source](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#source) object ([source_code](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/master/graphviz/files.py) - not scary) That would be rendered directly in jupyter.

Some things you are likely to do with it

Display it in jupter:

```
from IPython.display import SVG
graph = Source( tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns))
SVG(graph.pipe(format='svg'))
```

Save as png:

```
graph = Source( tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns))
graph.format = 'png'
graph.render('dtree_render',view=True)
```

Get the png image, save it and view it:

```
graph = Source( tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns))
png_bytes = graph.pipe(format='png')
with open('dtree_pipe.png','wb') as f:
    f.write(png_bytes)

from IPython.display import Image
Image(png_bytes)
```

If you are going to play with that lib here are the links to [examples](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) and [userguide](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)

Comment: This is how to install in Anaconda: `conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz`

Answer (score 25):

If, like me, you have a problem installing graphviz, you can visualize the tree by

1. exporting it with `export_graphviz` as shown in previous answers
2. Open the `.dot` file in a text editor
3. Copy the piece of code and paste it @ [webgraphviz.com](http://webgraphviz.com)

Answer (score 15):

Scikit learn recently introduced the `plot_tree` method to make this very easy (new in version 0.21 (May 2019)). Documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html).

Here's the minimum code you need:

```
from sklearn import tree
plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))  # customize according to the size of your tree
_ = tree.plot_tree(your_model_name, feature_names = X.columns)
plt.show()
```

`plot_tree` supports some arguments to beautify the tree. For example:

```
from sklearn import tree
plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))  
_ = tree.plot_tree(your_model_name, feature_names = X.columns, 
             filled=True, fontsize=6, rounded = True)
plt.show()
```

If you want to save the picture to a file, add the following line before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.savefig('filename.png')
```

If you want to view the rules in text format, there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57335067/10817844). It's more intuitive to read.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you could try using pydot for producing the png file from dot:

```
...
tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file='tree.dot') #produces dot file

import pydot
dotfile = StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file=dotfile)
pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dotfile.getvalue()).write_png("dtree2.png")
...
```

Comment: see new version pydotplus in comment @Alexey Shrub

Answer (score 8):

The following also works fine:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()

# Model (can also use single decision tree)
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)

# Train
model.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
# Extract single tree
estimator = model.estimators_[5]

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
# Export as dot file
export_graphviz(estimator, out_file='tree.dot', 
                feature_names = iris.feature_names,
                class_names = iris.target_names,
                rounded = True, proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, filled = True)

# Convert to png using system command (requires Graphviz)
from subprocess import call
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=600'])

# Display in jupyter notebook
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename = 'tree.png')
```

[image]

You can find the source [here](https://gist.github.com/WillKoehrsen/ff77f5f308362819805a3defd9495ffd)

Answer (score 6):

I copy and change a part of your code as the below:

```
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from os import system

data = read_csv('D:/training.csv')
Y = data.Y
X = data.ix[:,"X0":"X33"]

dtree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "entropy")
dtree = dtree.fit(X, Y)
```

After making sure you have dtree, which means that the above code runs well, you add the below code to visualize decision tree:

Remember to install graphviz first: pip install graphviz

```
import graphviz 
from graphviz import Source
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dtree, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
graph.render("name of file",view = True)
```

I tried with my data, visualization worked well and I got a pdf file viewed immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the contents of the export_graphviz file and you can paste the same in the [webgraphviz.com](http://webgraphviz.com) site.

You can check out the article on How to [visualize the decision tree in Python with graphviz](https://dataaspirant.com/2017/04/21/visualize-decision-tree-python-graphviz/) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way founded [here](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/trees_and_forests/visualize_a_decision_tree/) with [pydotplus](https://pypi.org/project/pydotplus/) (graphviz must be installed):

```
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus # installing pyparsing maybe needed
```

...

```
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(best_model, out_file=None, feature_names = X.columns)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the minimal code to have a nice looking graph with just 3 lines of code :

```py
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus

dot_data=tree.export_graphviz(dt,filled=True,rounded=True)
graph=pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)
graph.write_png('tree.png')  

plt.imshow(plt.imread('tree.png'))
```

I just added the `plt.imgshow` to view the graph in Jupyter Notebook. You can ignore it if you are only interested in saving the png file.

I installed the following dependencies:

```
pip3 install graphviz
pip3 install pydotplus
```

For MacOs the pip version of Graphviz did not work. Following Graphviz's [official documentation](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/) I installed it with brew and everything worked fine.

```
brew install graphviz
```

[image]

Comment: That's what really worked to me. I recommend to anyone seeking a solution to try with load_iris example database from sklearn.datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If you run into issues with grabbing the source .dot directly you can also use `Source.from_file` like this:

```
from graphviz import Source
from sklearn import tree
tree.export_graphviz(dtreg, out_file='tree.dot', feature_names=X.columns)
Source.from_file('tree.dot')
```