# export_graphviz return NoneType

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to visiualize my decisiontree.Below is the code which I have tried

```
 from StringIO import StringIO
 from sklearn import tree
 out = StringIO()
 clf =DecisionTreeClassifier(X,y)
 out = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=out)
 print out.getvalue()
```

Below is the error which i am getting

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-7b068216688f> in <module>()
  4 
  5 out = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=out)
 ---->  6 print out.getvalue()

 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getvalue'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817994/visualizing-decision-tree-in-scikit-learn

Answer (score 0):

The sklearn [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html) states that `export_graphviz` returns a string and it does so

> only if `out_file` is `None`

However, there are more problems with your code. As `export_graphviz` returns a **string**, once you assign it to `out`, you no longer have a `StringIO` object, but an `str` object. To save the returned value to a `StringIO` object, do not provide `out_file` and save to `out` as follows:

```
print >>out, tree.export_graphviz(clf)
```

Since you write `from StringIO import StringIO` I am assumming you are using Python 2.x.